# Elastic Terms aggregation return 0 with keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

below aggregation returns 0 even when I have data in index.

```
GET index_name/index_type/_search
{
"size": 0,
  "aggs": {
   "trms": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "su_name.keyword",
      "size": 10
  }
}
```

}
}

Following is the mapping of this index:

```
"properties": {
      "event_seq_no": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "event_time": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "status": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 500
          }
        },
        "fielddata": true
      },
      "su_name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 500
          }
        },
        "fielddata": true
      },
      "transaction_id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        },
        "fielddata": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have other indices with similar mapping and data and am able to fetch unique su_name. But for this particular index it returns 0. Can anyone please explain?

Comment: The query looks fine to me, may you please provide a couple of example documents from that index?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Nikolay. There was a problem with the mappings it's resolved now.

Comment: Thanks, good to know!